# Ubuntu 12.10 Live CD crash

Tags: 12.10, live-cd

Im trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 in my new system:

i7-3770K @ 4.2ghz | Noctua NH-D14 | EVGA 680 GTX OC |EVGA 460GTX | ASROCK Z77 Extreme4 | 8gb G.SKILL Ares DDR3 2133 | Agility 3 128 GB SSD |  RAID0 WD AAKS 1TB | Seagate Barracuda 7.2 2TB | Corsair AX850 | CM Storm Trooper

Im trying to run a Live CD from an USB, used dd , ubuntu creator and unetbootin with same results. It boots the graphical enviroment but after a while it crashes. I havent had any majore issues in the past installing ubuntu on my other machines, but this one i have no idea how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

¿Could it be something related to my graphics cards setup?

PD: Im running windows 7 atm, with no problems at all and ran lot of benchmarks so it isnt "hardware problems".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can sometime happen that the hardware drivers that 12.10 was packaged with, are not 
yet "ready" for the system/hardware you have. You might have to wait for another 6 months for the next distro, unless and until some new driver / patch comes up.

Since you have an 8GB of RAM and you have already said that you are running Windows 7, may I suggest you to check if VirtualBox based Linux / Ubuntu is running on your system? You may also try to install a Wubi based Linux version, for the purposes of trying.